# How to select distinct rows in EntitySpaces 2012

Tags: c#, linq, entityspaces

I am using ***EntitySpaces 2012*** architecture which provides ORM mapping and built-in methods to write your SQL query using it's libraries (just like LINQ to SQL). The problem is, I cannot select distinct rows from a table using EntitySpaces *Select* Query. Currently, I am doing it as follows

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ActualData objAct = new ActualDataQuery();
objAct.Select(objAct.Year.Distinct);
    dt = objAct.LoadDataTable();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    FillCombo(dt);
}
```

I have put a breakpoint as well on the line where my datatable object is getting load, and it is showing that the distinct rows are present there multiple times (means distinct not working).
[image: Distinct not working in EntitySpaces]
 I have also go through the complete documentation of EntitySpaces but there's nothing regarding *distinct* keyword. Also I found nothing on the internet related to this problem as there's no forum for EntitySpaces2012. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of [Select distinct](http://esdocs.pixeo.be/default.htm?turl=Modules%2F6%2FDocuments%2Fselectdistinct.htm) query from http://esdocs.pixeo.be/:

```
EmployeesQuery q = new EmployeesQuery("e");
q.es.Distinct = true;
q.Select(q.EmployeeID);
```

You can use [Distinct method](http://esdocs.pixeo.be/default.htm?turl=Modules%2F4%2FXMLDocuments%2FReference%2Fhtml%2FM_EntitySpaces_DynamicQuery_esQueryItem_Distinct.htm) too.

So, your query might look like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ActualData objAct = new ActualDataQuery();
objAct.Distinct = true;
objAct.Select(objAct.Year);
dt = objAct.LoadDataTable();
```

Note: i'm not familiar with EntitySpaces.

Good luck!